# Odoo 10 - stock_move vs stock_picking

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I would like to understand differences between:

```
stock_move table
```

and

```
stock_picking table
```

what are they both used for? which are the differences between both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stock picking represents an operation, let's say, you taking some goods from location A to location B. You move 10 item A and 10 item B.
A stock move represents the action of moving 10 items A from location A to location B. Another stock move is the action of moving 10 item B from location A to location B.

A stock picking may contain several stock moves.
The stock picking is the moving operation. Stock moves represent individual stock movement.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that move is the move in the accounting way, which means that you move a product from stock to customer. Whereas picking is the physical move from stock to a package.